# Unable to autoload constant Featured_image, expected C:/Sites/pickyourchoice/app/models/featured_image.rb to define it

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4.1

i have a model Featured_images in my rails application and in my view page i need  to show all the data stored with this model table .
In my controller i have a method named index

```
def index
  @featured_images = Featured_image.all
end
```

in my view

```
<% @featured_images.each do |h| %>
    <div class="item">
        <%=image_tag h.pg_images.url(:medium), :class=>'img-responsive' %>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use

```
@featured_images = FeaturedImage.all
```

instead of

```
@featured_images = Featured_image.all
```

and your model should be like

```
class FeaturedImage < ActiveRecord::Base

end
```

Comment: hi thanks for ans ,i have tried it .now no error but in view no data is coming .

Comment: is it beacause i dont have any strong parameter defintion for featured_images model?

Comment: may be , can you check the data in table using console.

Comment: i have data in database in the table .when  i am doing inspect element it is showing it is not getting inside of loop.

Comment: what you are used for image processing i.e. carrierwave or paperclip.

Comment: i tried defining strong parameters def images_params
        params.require(:user).permit(:phno)
    end

Comment: for image processing i have used paperclip

Comment: you need to define strong params   in controller not in model.

Comment: param is missing or the value is empty: featured_image this is the error .          private 
def image_params
 params.require(:featured_image).permit(:pg_images)
end

Comment: post your create method .

Comment: i am using Active_admin to add data to the model so i don't have create method in my home_controller and i want to show data in index.html.erb so i have defined index method in homecontroller .

Comment: Then post your admin file where you create featured images.

Comment: permit_params :image,:pg_images
form multipart: true  do |f|
  
    
    f.input :pg_images, :required => false, :as => :file
    
  
  f.actions
 end

Comment: check data from console for pg_images column. i think data is not inserted in this field.